# Remote access of an iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, remote-access, screensharing

I want to get remote access of my iOS app running on one iPad in another iPad. Is there a way in iOS SDK to achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No, there is no 'remote control'/'screen sharing' in iOS

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not. You can mirror the screen to another device using AirPlay, but there is no way to "drive" the device remotely. (There's an app called "Reflector" that lets you mirror you iOS device onto your Mac, but it's view only.)